# How to select only some values form dictionary in one of column of hive table?

Tags: python, sql, hive

Suppose this is my hive table

`A                   B                           C` 
`a1        {'age':0,'name':b1, 'id':100}         c1`
`a2        {'age':1,'name':b2, 'id':200}         c2`
`a3        {'age':2,'name':b3, 'id':300}         c3`
How to select only this
`age name`
`0    b1`
`1    b2`
`2    b3`
using SQL query on hash table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the result you wanted you can use the following query:

```
SELECT get_json_object(B,'$.age')  as age,
       get_json_object(B,'$.name') as name
FROM table_name
```

Where `B` is your column name

Comment: My main purpose is to convert that above result into pandas DataFrame, do you know any efficient way to that too?

Comment: You can read about SQL to Pandas DataFrame here https://datatofish.com/sql-to-pandas-dataframe/